# Payumoney payment gateway issue window leak

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am getting error while processing the payment with card using payumoney

here is my code :

```
 private fun showAlertWithTextInputLayout(context: Context) {
    val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(context)
    textInputLayout.setPadding(
        resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_19), // if you look at android alert_dialog.xml, you will see the message textview have margin 14dp and padding 5dp. This is the reason why I use 19 here
        0,
        resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_19),
        0
    )
    val input = EditText(context)
    textInputLayout.hint = "Coin"
    input.inputType= InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
    textInputLayout.addView(input)
    val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Add Coins")
        .setView(textInputLayout)
        .setMessage("How many coin wants to add?")
        .setPositiveButton("Add") { dialog, _ ->
            if (!input.text.equals("") ){

                launchPayUMoneyFlow(input.text.toString())
                dialog.dismiss()
                finish()
            }else{
                AppLogger.toast("Please enter some value.")
            }
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.cancel()
        }.create()
    alert.show()
}
private var mAppPreference: AppPreference? = null
private var mPaymentParams: PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam? = null
private val isDisableExitConfirmation = false
lateinit var binding: ActivityPaymentBinding
lateinit var usetId:String
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_payment)
    initView()
}
private fun initView() {
    if(MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!=null && MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.id!=null ){
        usetId = MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.id!!
    }
    mAppPreference = AppPreference()
    binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.cardAddGift.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.cardReceivedGift.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.cardRedeem.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.cardTransctionHistory.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.cardSendGift.setOnClickListener(this)
    selectSandBoxEnv()
    setupCitrusConfigs()
}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val points=MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.referralpoints
    if (points!=null){
        binding.tvTotalPonits.text=points
    }
}
private fun setupCitrusConfigs() {
    val appEnvironment = (application as MoodApplication).getAppEnvironment()
    if (appEnvironment === AppEnvironment.PRODUCTION) {
        Toast.makeText(this@WalletActivity, "Environment Set to Production", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this@WalletActivity, "Environment Set to SandBox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
private fun selectSandBoxEnv() {
    (application as MoodApplication).setAppEnvironment(AppEnvironment.SANDBOX)
    setupCitrusConfigs()
}
private fun launchPayUMoneyFlow(payMoney:String) {

    val payUmoneyConfig = PayUmoneyConfig.getInstance()
    payUmoneyConfig.doneButtonText = "Pay"

    //Use this to set your custom title for the activity
    payUmoneyConfig.payUmoneyActivityTitle = "Pay :"+payMoney

    payUmoneyConfig.disableExitConfirmation(isDisableExitConfirmation)

    val builder = PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder()

    var amount = 0.0
    try {
        amount = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(payMoney)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val txnId = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ""
    //String txnId = "TXNID720431525261327973";
    val phone = MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.phoneNumber
    val productName = mAppPreference!!.productInfo
    val firstName = mAppPreference!!.firstName
    val email = MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()!!.data!!.email
    val udf1 = ""
    val udf2 = ""
    val udf3 = ""
    val udf4 = ""
    val udf5 = ""
    val udf6 = ""
    val udf7 = ""
    val udf8 = ""
    val udf9 = ""
    val udf10 = ""

    val appEnvironment = (application as MoodApplication).getAppEnvironment()
    builder.setAmount(amount.toString())
        .setTxnId(txnId)
        .setPhone(phone)
        .setProductName(productName)
        .setFirstName(firstName)
        .setEmail(email)
        .setsUrl(appEnvironment.surl())
        .setfUrl(appEnvironment.furl())
        .setUdf1(udf1)
        .setUdf2(udf2)
        .setUdf3(udf3)
        .setUdf4(udf4)
        .setUdf5(udf5)
        .setUdf6(udf6)
        .setUdf7(udf7)
        .setUdf8(udf8)
        .setUdf9(udf9)
        .setUdf10(udf10)
        .setIsDebug(appEnvironment.debug())
        .setKey(appEnvironment.merchant_Key())
        .setMerchantId(appEnvironment.merchant_ID())

    try {
        mPaymentParams = builder.build()
        mPaymentParams = calculateServerSideHashAndInitiatePayment1(mPaymentParams!!)
        if (AppPreference.selectedTheme != -1) {
            PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(mPaymentParams, this@WalletActivity, AppPreference.selectedTheme, mAppPreference!!.isOverrideResultScreen)
        } else {
            PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(mPaymentParams, this@WalletActivity, R.style.AppTheme_default, mAppPreference!!.isOverrideResultScreen)
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       //            payNowButton!!.isEnabled = true
    }

}
private fun calculateServerSideHashAndInitiatePayment1(paymentParam: PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam): PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam {

    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    val params = paymentParam.params
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.KEY]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.TXNID]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.AMOUNT]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.PRODUCT_INFO]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.FIRSTNAME]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.EMAIL]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.UDF1]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.UDF2]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.UDF3]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.UDF4]!! + "|")
    stringBuilder.append(params[PayUmoneyConstants.UDF5]!! + "||||||")

    val appEnvironment = (application as MoodApplication).getAppEnvironment()
    stringBuilder.append(appEnvironment.salt())

    val hash = Membership.hashCal(stringBuilder.toString())
    paymentParam.setMerchantHash(hash)

    return paymentParam
}
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // Result Code is -1 send from Payumoney activity
        Log.d("MainActivity", "request code $requestCode resultcode $resultCode")

        try {
            if (requestCode == PayUmoneyFlowManager.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                val transactionResponse = data.getParcelableExtra<TransactionResponse>(PayUmoneyFlowManager
                    .INTENT_EXTRA_TRANSACTION_RESPONSE)
                val resultModel = data.getParcelableExtra<ResultModel>(PayUmoneyFlowManager.ARG_RESULT)
                if (transactionResponse != null && transactionResponse.getPayuResponse() != null) {
                    if (transactionResponse.transactionStatus == TransactionResponse.TransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
                        val payuResponse = transactionResponse.getPayuResponse()
                        var gson: Gson = Gson()
                        var response = gson.fromJson(payuResponse, PayumoneyResponse::class.java)
                        Log.e("@@Response", response.toString())
                        addoinsApi(response.result.amount)
                    } else {

                    }

                } else if (resultModel != null && resultModel.error != null) {
                    Log.d(Membership.TAG, "Error response : " + resultModel.error.transactionResponse)
                } else {
                    Log.d(Membership.TAG, "Both objects are null!")
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }

private fun addoinsApi(amount: String) {
    AndroidNetworking.post(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=addCoins")
        .addUrlEncodeFormBodyParameter("userid",usetId)
        .addUrlEncodeFormBodyParameter("addcoins",amount)
        .setTag("addCoins")
        .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
        .build()
        .getAsString(object : StringRequestListener {
            override fun onResponse(response: String) {
                AppLogger.e("addCoins response","====="+response)
                val loginModel: LoginModel? =MoodApplication.sharedPreference.getValueUserLogedIn()
                loginModel!!.data!!.referralpoints=(Integer.parseInt(loginModel.data!!.referralpoints.toString())+java.lang.Double.parseDouble(amount).toInt()).toString()
                MoodApplication.sharedPreference.saveSigninUser(loginModel)
                binding.tvTotalPonits.text=loginModel.data!!.referralpoints
                AlertDialog.Builder(this@WalletActivity)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage("Coins successfully added.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { dialog, whichButton -> dialog.dismiss() }.show()

            }

            override fun onError(error: ANError) {
                // handle error
                AppLogger.toast(error.localizedMessage)
                Log.e(" addCoins Error", "=======" + error.localizedMessage)
            }
        })
    }
   }
```

Please help me I am getting an error like this :

```
 E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.payumoney.core.SdkWebViewActivityNew has leaked window DecorView@1abf316[SdkWebViewActivityNew] that was originally added here
```

I would appreciate every answer on StackOverflow

Comment: The issue is related to activity being stopped or destroyed without dismissing an existing dialog. So you should dismiss any ongoing dialogs in onDestroy of your activity.

Comment: but explain to me how to dismiss dialog in this code

Comment: `dialog.dimiss()`

Comment: its not global variable I have done dissmiss already

Comment: please share code where I need to dismiss this